# VM Ware does not recognize USB devices

Tags: usb, vmware

VMware does not recognize any USB device.
How do I fix USB detection?

System

- Windows 7 (64 bit)
- Front USB 3.0
- VMware Player 4.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware Player 4.0.4 does not detect devices on USB 3.0
Use USB 2 to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

As per Thorsten Niehues answer, you can see more details here

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1025956

Answer (score 0):

you can use VMware Player 5.01 can be downloaded freely from [here.](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/)
that has support of USB 3.0 and many more new features. you can find more info [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Player)

Comment: but this doesnt support windows 7