# VM ware still doesn't work very well even with VM Player 5.0.2 on an external USB3

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, ssd

I have had problems trying to use VM images on an Integral 512Gb external ssd with USB3. My new Dell Latitude E6230 has two USB3 ports. I *was* on VMPlayer 4.0.4 which works extremely well when the VM image is on the *internal* ssd drive, but slowed to a crawl when I I tried to use the external ssd attached to either of the USB3 ports. I mean suicidally slow. I got all excited when I read one of the other articles here:

[VM Ware does not recognize USB devices](https://superuser.com/questions/459440/vm-ware-does-not-recognize-usb-devices)

I immediately updated to VM Player 5.0.2 and waited expectantly. I first checked that I had the same high speed response with the same VM image copied to the internal ssd. However, I was extremely disappointed that the improvement on the external ssd (and a Lexar USB3 128Gb memory stick as well) was marginal at best.

*Please* can someone help me? While I can obviously use the internal ssd, its only got 256Gb so with all the other bloatware I have to use (Microsoft of course the main problem) there isn't that much space for all but a few smallish VM images.

I look forward to some assistance.

Comment: What are the speed specifications for the USB3 device?  I have no problem with performance problems on either USB3 external HDDs nor USB3 flash drives using the current version of VMWare

Comment: Thanks Ramhound - I'm a bit thick (a bit? a lot!) so not sure how to answer that. Where would I find that out? Interested to hear you have no problems - there is hope then!

Comment: Lets start with the advertised speeds.

Comment: OK, here we go. The Integral 512GB ssd has advertised Read up to 220MB/s and write up to 120MB/s. The Lexar 128GB Jump drive has 100MB/s and 55 MB/s. Hope this helps.

Comment: I assume you know the difference between USB 3.0 ports and USB 2.0 ports right?  Have you tried a powered USb 3.0 hub?  If you are trying this on battery power I suspect the device would have major problems writting at those advertised speeds.

Comment: Yes I'm OK with the ports, but what you say about a powered hub is interesting. I have a USB2 one (not with me on site) but not a USB3 one yet (only a non-powered one that I use as a splitter). Maybe that should be my next port of call. Thanks for the advice - it seems counterintuitive that I should get a lower speed with an ssd working off the laptop when the USB2 hdds I've used previously have been a lot faster (but still irritating - which is why I was so disappointed with the ssd). Must say the transfer rate is fine with files, its just the VM that's rubbish. Cheers for now and thanks.

Comment: Mind you, I just thought - what about my Lexar USB3 memory stick? That seems to be giving me exactly the same problem. Maybe VM Player just doesn't like USB3 at all? I know you said yours works fine - very confused but I'll see about the USB3 powered hub.

Comment: I almost always use Hubs because of the amount of USB devices I use.  Would have said something, didn't think anything of it, until I thought about the fact your using a laptop and the possible power requirements over USB for the device.

Answer (score 2):

- In my experience some flash drives are very slow compared to external hard drives or SATA-to-USB attached SSDs.  You might want to try using an actual hard drive (such as the one that was previously in your system if you still have it/upgraded it) or SSD connected to a USB 3.0 enclosure.
- Make sure you don't have USB 2.0 compatibility enabled in the BIOS.
- Make sure you have the proper chipset and USB 3.0 drivers installed.  You may need to go to support.dell.com to obtain the right ones.
- If you go the actual external hard drive/SSD route and still have issues with USB 3.0, use an eSATA enclosure instead.

Comment: Thanks ultra - I'll have a check and come back to you. A colleague did have a look on dell support and upgraded some drivers but I'll go back through the process. As Ramhound has no problems with his, it gives me hope.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about USB2.0 compatibility in the BIOS so assume its OK. I think I'm doomed to copying the VM images to the internal ssd when I need them. BTW what does 'a USB 3.0 enclosure' mean? I've tried to get the idiots guide on Google but no luck. Are you talking about a powered hub like Ramhound?

Comment: @DaveStephens - A eSATA & USB 2.0/3.0 enclosure turns a 2.5" or 3.5" internal drive into an external drive.  You would connect the enclosure of an eSATA port.  This would elminate the question about power and boost your speeds by ten fold.